# How to Pull a Single Column from a Table Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

I am trying to pull the subject list from this [website](https://www.fda.gov/ICECI/EnforcementActions/WarningLetters/2017/default.htm)

my code so far

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
quote_page = 'https://www.fda.gov/ICECI/EnforcementActions/WarningLetters/2017/default.htm'
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
soup.prettify()
print soup.find_all("table", id = "WarningLetter_sortid")
```

I can find the table but i can't seem to figure out how to extract the subject column. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can locate all the rows in the table (except the first header row) and get the fourth `td` element for every row:

```
rows = soup.select("table#WarningLetter_sortid tr")[1:]
print([row('td')[3].get_text(strip=True) for row in rows])
```

You can also do it in one go with the `nth-of-type()` CSS selector:

```
print([row.get_text(strip=True) 
       for row in soup.select("table#WarningLetter_sortid tr > td:nth-of-type(4)")])
```